# Making all mainmatter headers and footers be this way, even on new-chapter pages

Tags: header-footer, memoir, page-numbering

I'm using `memoir`, in case it makes a difference.

Given this reminder (mostly for myself) of what recto and verso mean:

[image: recto and verso]

On all `\mainmatter` pages (even ones that start a new chapter), I'm trying to change my headers so that:

1. Verso header is always empty
2. Recto header always has the words "TEX ROCKS" in the center

And my footers so that ta:

3. Verso footer always has page number on the left
4. Recto footer always has page number on the right

Is there a simple way to make this so, without redefining everything?

Comment: What is `\thetitle`? The chapter title?

Comment: No it's the value set by `\title{...}` for me. I don't know what package is making it available but it gets the job done. For convenience I'll just put a static string in my question.

Comment: `\@title` then, however, this could be empty if `\maketitle` has been used.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I changed the question to not mention the title at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memoir` pagestyles are quite easy to create. Use `\makepagestyle{foo}` and the commands `\makeevenhead{foo}{left stuff}{center stuff}{right stuff}` and `\makeoddhead{foo}{left stuff}{center stuff}{right stuff}` (and the similar commands `\makeevenfoot` and `\makeoddfoot`)

To provide the pagestyle for the `chapter` start page, I kicked the `\thispagestyle{chapter}` out and replaced it with `mainmatterstyle`.  I am no `memoir` expert (but I should use it more, I am sure ;-)), there is perhaps an easier way to provide the chapter style.

```
\documentclass{memoir}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{%
  \thispagestyle{chapter}}{%
    \thispagestyle{mainmatterstyle}%
  }{%
}{}


\makepagestyle{mainmatterstyle}

\makeatletter
\makeevenfoot{mainmatterstyle}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mainmatterstyle}{}{}{\thepage}

\makeevenhead{mainmatterstyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mainmatterstyle}{}{\@title}{}
\makeatother

\title{\LaTeXe\ rocks}
\author{A. U. Thor}

\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatterstyle}

\chapter{First}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

**Verso**
[image]

**Recto**
[image]

Comment: Great answer, plus it allows me a lot of flexibility in changing things up within my headers/footers!

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without using `xpatch` at all?